# Elasticsearch: facet or aggregation returning doc counts over multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, facet

I have an elasticsearch document structure for which I'd like to have a terms facet (or aggragation) for which I obtain the number of documents independently of the field in which they appear.

For example, le following result shows both the documents and facetted search result:

```
    {
        "_shards": {
            "failed": 0, "successful": 5, "total": 5
        },
        "hits": {
            "hits": [
                {
                    "_id": "003", "_index": "test", "_score": 1.0, "_type": "test",
                    "_source": {
                        "root": {
                            "content": [
                                "five",
                                "five",
                                "five"
                            ],
                            "title": "four"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_id": "002", "_index": "test", "_score": 1.0, "_type": "test",
                    "_source": {
                        "root": {
                            "content": "two three",
                            "title": "three"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_id": "001", "_index": "test", "_score": 1.0, "_type": "test",
                    "_source": {
                        "root": {
                            "content": "one two",
                            "title": "one"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "max_score": 1.0, "total": 3
        },
        "facets": {
            "terms": {
                "_type": "terms", "missing": 0, "other": 0,
                "terms": [
                    {
                        "count": 2,
                        "term": "two"
                    },
                    {
                        "count": 2,
                        "term": "three"
                    },
                    {
                        "count": 2,
                        "term": "one"
                    },
                    {
                        "count": 1,
                        "term": "four"
                    },
                    {
                        "count": 1,
                        "term": "five"
                    }
                ],
                "total": 8
            }
        },
        "timed_out": false,
        "took": 18,
    }
```

We can see that the terms "one" and "three" have counts of 2 (once for each field of the same doc) where I would like them to have a count of 1. The only term with a count of 2 should be "two".

I looked into aggregation to see if it could help but it doesn't seem to work with multiple fields (or I have missed something).

It would have been nice to build a "terms" facet on "root" rather than the individual fields... but that doesn't seem possible either.

Any ideas, how to work this out ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the script in terms aggregation to achieve this.
Inside the script , collect the tokens from both the field  , do a set union operation and then return the set.

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "genders" : {
            "terms" : {
                "script" : "union(doc['content'].values, doc['title'].values) "
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to see how to apply the union operation in whichever language you use to use as script language.

Answer (score 0):

you could add new field, which keeps unique terms from both content and title fields, and make facet aggregation on it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'll do if I don't find an alternative, but I rather not duplicate the content if it were possible.